# Change Image of Image View Dynamically From URL

Tags: android, url, imageview

Is there a method of which I can use to pass in a url with an image and afterwhich have it displayed in the image view of an android application? Sorry if the question sounds simple, i am new to programming and not too sure the technical terms to it.

Answer (score 1):

First you will need the app permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Secondly, you can load the image from a URL using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2471935/how-to-load-an-imageview-by-url-in-android).